# Why isn't there a BOOLEANP predicate?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

To check for a symbol, one might use `symbolp`. To check for a number, one might use `numberp`. And so on…

Why is there no `booleanp` to check for a boolean value? Of course I can use

```
(defun booleanp (x)
  (or (null x)
      (equal x t)))
```

but is there an easier (built-in) way of doing this? If not, is there a special reason, why just *this* predicate is missing?

Comment: Is boolean an actual type, or just a convention for how to interpret other types?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question correctly (probably not), but since `(type-of t)` returns `boolean` I thought that it is an actual type. Isn't it? OTOH `nil` is (of course) not of type `boolean`, since it's equivalent to the empty list. Hmmm…

Comment: boolean is a type. see http://l1sp.org/cl/boolean

Comment: NIL is of type boolean. It is also of type LIST. An object may be of many types. Consider 1: it's of type bit, integer, and unsigned-byte.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know the exact history of `numberp`, `symbolp`, the boolean type, and other type predicates, but with the availability of the generic type predicate `typep` it is not necessary to have a separate predicate for every type. A short way to see if something is of type `boolean` is `(typep object 'boolean)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd dare to guess that the real reason for this is that even though only `NIL` and `T` are `(TYPEP 'BOOLEAN)`, any value is a valid boolean expression. I.e. any value except for `NIL` is considered true in an `IF` form. Thus, the usefulness of a `BOOLEANP` would be limited, if not harmful as it would return false for things that are perfectly valid input to the conditional forms.